# How can I close the object created with the Application.OpenForms[] method without closing the form?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a c# program and approxmatiely there is 20 Form Page in it. I have 3 class in this program and one of them  for loop. In this loop, I change TextBox,Label,Listview etc. of another page (I call as Auto Page). And I create an object of Auto Page like,

```
while(True)
{
Auto_Page auto_Page = (Auto_Page )Application.OpenForms["Auto_Page "];
auto_Page.textbox1.Text="123";
}
```

But I learned this cause memory leak.

So I did dispose object auto_Page (auto_Page.Dispose()). But unfortunetly this form closed (yes i am bad programmer). I used "using" statement but this for creating object with "new" parameter . So can you help me? What do you prefer for this situation.

Comment: You don't create anything there you just get a reference to an already created form so if you don't intend to close/destroy it don't dispose it.

Comment: Yes, Ralf it is True. But every loop is about 100 ms speed. And this program runs so long. That means is so much object reference. Then suddenly i get Win 32 windows program creating handle error. I think because of that. what should  I do?

Comment: Why do you loop over it? Maybe try store the reference and change the text through there. And if you have 20 Auto page, then create 20 instance put it in a list then you can do what ever.

Comment: That problem is then not connected to the shown code. But you are saying that you also change other controls in the mentioned loop. Those controls might have the need to recreate their handle with the change you apply to them and you end up beeing short on handles. You might want to try removing adding different controls here and check with what control you end up having the mentioned problem. With that knowledge you can dig deeper or try here again.